# Exporting a multi excel files into one file

Tags: export, programming, data, excel, data-structures

Suppose a list of students'grades in excel:

["excel files"](https://gofile.io/d/of258i)

I want to write a program separate student grades to their respective classes and then write them in one excel file. What should I do?. Something like this

Comment: You could use `Import` for your different files, do what you have to do as `List` manipulations, then `Export`.

Comment: @anderstood Yes, I just import them, but my problem is how to sort or assign each student to his grade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** Using the provided files.

Since the Excel files have no header, importing as a `Dataset` is not possible. The easiest way is to add headers to the Excel file and use the code from the comments. If that is not possible then

```
classGrades = 
 Import["~/Downloads/GG.xlsx"] // First // 
   MapAt[Round, #, {All, 1}] & // (* Change class id to integer *)
   Map[AssociationThread[{"class", "grade"}, #] &];

classStudents = 
 Import["~/Downloads/C11.xlsx"] // First // 
   MapAt[Round, #, {All, 1}] & // (* Change class id to integer *)
   Map[AssociationThread[{"class", "student"}, #] &];

JoinAcross[classStudents, classGrades, Key["class"]]

{<|"class" -> 3080056, "student" -> "s5", "grade" -> "Abs"|>,
 <|"class" -> 2978221, "student" -> "s8", "grade" -> 8.|>,
 <|"class" -> 3170243, "student" -> "s3", "grade" -> 13.|>}
```

Class id's present in both files are joined (inner join). For a left join

```
JoinAcross[classStudents, classGrades, Key["class"], "Left"]
```

Check the documentation for other join options.

---

`Import` the files as `Dataset`, convert to `Normal` which will give a list of `Association`. Combine the 4 separate files using `Join`. You should end up with

```
classGrades = {<|"class" -> 221, "grade" -> 20|>, <|"class" -> 223, "grade" -> "Abs"|>,
               <|"class" -> 224, "grade" -> 8|>, <|"class" -> 225, "grade" -> 11|>}


classStudents = {<|"class" -> 221, "student" -> "s1"|>, <|"class" -> 223, "student" -> "s2"|>,
                 <|"class" -> 224, "student" -> "s3"|>, <|"class" -> 225, "student" -> "s4"|>}
```

Then use `JoinAcross` to combine them

```
combined = JoinAcross[classStudents, classGrades, Key["class"]]

{<|"class" -> 221, "student" -> "s1", "grade" -> 20|>,
 <|"class" -> 223, "student" -> "s2", "grade" -> "Abs"|>,
 <|"class" -> 224, "student" -> "s3", "grade" -> 8|>,
 <|"class" -> 225, "student" -> "s4", "grade" -> 11|>}
```

Comment: Thanks! but what if my data is large? I tried this but did not work `classGrades = {<|"class" -> C1[[All, 1]], "grade" -> GG[[All, 2]]|>}' C1 is class one, which is a excel file have over 400 student, and GG is the excel file for all the four class.

Comment: @user75330 How are you importing the files? Should be like `Import["path/to/file.xlsx", {"Dataset", 1}, HeaderLines -> 1]`. You do not have to construct the association manually, `Import` will do that. Edit your post and provide a sample of data for each of the files that can be cut and pasted, not images, so I can show a working example.

Comment: @user75330 What are the columns in CA1.xlsx and ASTRXXX_EXAM_12.xlsx? How do they correspond to the images in your question, which does not mention either of those names?

Comment: Well the file GG.xlsx has two columns  like my first table in my questions, the file C11.xlsx has also two columns like my second table and so on.

Comment: @user75330 In that case `C1` should be `classGrades` and `GG` should be `classStudents`. Like I said, there should be no need to manually construct the associations for them. `classGrades = Import["C11.xlsx",...] // Normal`

Comment: That's right! but did not work?

Comment: Would you please provide a neat example? Like in you solution you put all the data manually, I am I right?

Comment: Yes, I did it manually. So, reverse the process. Using `classGrades` from my answer, `Export["cg.csv", Dataset@classGrades]` then `classGrades = Import["cg.csv", "Dataset", HeaderLines -> 1] // Normal`. I used CSV because exporting dataset to XLSX does not work correctly, but import does.

Comment: So your solution will not work since associations is needed.

Comment: @user75330 I don't understand your comment. `Import` as dataset + `Normal` generates `Association` as I demonstrated in the example above.

Comment: Ok, If I write `classGrades = {<|"class" -> C1[[All, 1]], "grade" -> GG[[All, 2]]|>};~ AND `classGrades = {<|"class" -> C1[[All, 1]], "grade" -> GG[[All, 2]]|>};~ ` and then join them by `JoinAcross` MW gave me `{}`

Comment: Well of course, you are constructing `classGrades` incorrectly, `classGrades = Normal@Import["path/to/file.xlsx", {"Dataset", 1}, HeaderLines -> 1]`

Comment: What are the headers in your Excel files? Does GG have headers 'class' and 'grade'? Does C11 have headers 'class' and 'student'?

Comment: No, The GG header just like my first table in above, and C11 just like the second table.

Comment: or in other words no header in GG and C11 Excel files.

Comment: I believe that you did not understand my question very well, let make things simple. Suppose that I have two Excel files, namely GG and C11. Note that GG has the grade and ID numbers of student s of all four classes while C11 have the student name and their ID  for class1. I hope that it is clear to you.

Comment: Please provide sample files via Google drive or Google docs or pastebin or Dropbox.

Comment: Ok, I just did.

Comment: @user75330 Updated answer using provided files.

Comment: Thanks so much! Last thing how do I export the result in .xlsx formate?

Comment: `joined = JoinAcross[....]` then `Export["joined.xlsx",  Values@joined]`. If you want headers in the Excel file then `Export["joined.xlsx", 
 Values@joined // Prepend[First@DeleteDuplicates@Keys@joined]]`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate what you did. Lastly, Can we make `s5,s8,s3` in order such as` s3,s5,s8`

Comment: `joined // SortBy[#student &]`, replace `student` by `grade` or `class` to sort by that value, use `ReverseSortBy` to reverse the sort order.

Comment: If this answers all of your questions, would you mind accepting my answer? If not, let me know if you need help with anything else.

Comment: Thanks so much!